# compare two records from now to end of year/month postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to compute a Year To Date performance of a stock.
My database is simple as per below

[image]

However I am struggling to find the right query

So far I am only able to show details for one date, surely it must be a more technical way to achieve this. If you would have some tutorial recommend or fairly junior documentation, it would be also greatly appreciated.

The expected result would be :

[image]

My best query so far, it gives the answer though

```
SELECT t1.contract_id, t1.timestamp_tick, t1.close, t2.timestamp_tick, t2.close, t2.close / NULLIF(t1.close,0) -1 as perf FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM candles where id in (
SELECT max(id)  FROM public.candles WHERE extract(year from timestamp_tick)= '2022' and freq = 1380
group by contract_id 
    ) order by contract_id
) as t1

    INNER JOIN

(
SELECT * FROM candles where id in (
SELECT max(id)  FROM public.candles WHERE extract(year from timestamp_tick)= '2023' and freq = 1380
group by contract_id 
)
) as t2 
ON t1.contract_id = t2.contract_id  order by t1.contract_id
```

Comment: What is the formula you're using for performance using the columns you've provided as variables in the formula?

Comment: @MacGyver I have updated the query with the performance formula, does it help?

Comment: I'd prefer to know in words (English) and names of variables.  The query cannot provide this detail when it's incorrect.

Comment: This would be standard, but I'm not understanding what you have simplified or what the max values are for.  I can only guess.  Performance (Value), % = ((Value – Min) / (Max – Min)) * 100%

Comment: @MacGyver I understand now. the formula is close of last_day_2023 / close of last_day_2022 -1 or with my variable last_day being the max(timestamp of the year). I retrieve it in a weird way indeed using the max(id) instead of the year

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified example of how I would do this.  This solution does not allow for stocks missing any trades within a period (in this case, years) or with a period closing value of `0`.

```
with yr_closing as (
  select distinct on (contract_id, date_part('year', timestamp))
         date_part('year', timestamp) as year_close, *
    from candles
   order by contract_id, date_part('year', timestamp), timestamp desc
)
select *, 1.0 * close/(lag(close) over w) - 1 as perf  
  from yr_closing
window w as (partition by contract_id order by year_close);
```

The yr_closing [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH) gets the last row for each year that the stock was traded.   You specified that you are interested in only year-to-date, but this could be adapted to produce historical year-over-year and month-to-date performance measures with a single pass.

The [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) is Postgres magic that gets the last row of the year.  It is well worth learning how to exploit it.

The [`date_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) simply reduces the timestamp column to the year number, same as `extract()`.

The main query uses the [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#id-1.5.8.28.6.2.2.7.1.1.1) [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/tutorial-window.html) to make the prior row available in the current row.

The main query also illustrates the Postgres [`WINDOW window_name AS (window_definition)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WINDOW) for no reason other than it is very convenient and I curse loudly when using other DBMSes because they do not have this feature.

Please see the [working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BDLyVkAq).

Answer (score -1):

Remove your order by and add the concat(round( functions.  Otherwise what you have in your question looks good.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mzopNiVexVKwh9HLHRde1n/0

```
SELECT t1.contract_id, t1.close_date, t1.close_price, t2.close_date, t2.close_price, concat(ROUND(t2.close_price / t1.close_price - 1, 2) * 100, '%') FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM stockx where tx_id in (
SELECT max(tx_id)  FROM stockx WHERE YEAR(close_date)= '2022'
group by contract_id 
)
) as t1

    INNER JOIN

(
SELECT * FROM stockx where tx_id in (
SELECT max(tx_id)  FROM stockx WHERE YEAR(close_date)= '2023'
group by contract_id 
)
) as t2 
ON t1.contract_id = t2.contract_id  order by t1.contract_id
```